# Number of combinations of multiple variables with a condition

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have the following situation where for each variable, one of the proceeding values is selected.

```
Variable 1: 1,2,3
Variable 2: 1,2

Variable 3: CONDITION: 1 if VAR2 is 1. 1 OR 2 if VAR2 is 2.

Variable 4: 1,2,3
Variable 5: 1,2,3,4,5
Variable 6: 1,2,3,4,5
Variable 7: 1,2,3,4,5
```

I believe if it were not for the condition, there would be $3\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5=4500$ combinations. But the condition on Variable 3 means that the actual number of combinations should be lower but I'm not sure how to calculate that.

I'm thinking that I should calculate some value to subtract from $4500$ but can't figure out what value that would be.

Comment: Tests give me 3375 as the answer. Not 100% sure if that's right of course but wondering how to get to that if it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all values of each variable are equally likely (*uniformly distributed*) and the the choices of values for distinct variables are independent, with the exception of the variables 2 and 3, then we just have to analyze the possibilities for those two. There are 3 of them:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm{VAR}_2 & \mathrm{VAR}_3 \\
\hline 
1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 \\
2 & 2
\end{array}
$$
In other words, out of the $2 \cdot 2 = 4$ possible pairs of values for those two variables if they were independently chosen, we only get $3$ of them. So the total number of possibilities is
$$
3 \cdot \color{blue}{\tfrac34 \cdot2 \cdot 2} \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 
= 3 \cdot \color{blue}{3} \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 
= 3375. 
$$